# Is it possible that two exact same inputs give two different outputs using the Google Cloud API (advanced)

Tags: google-translate

We are working for a customer implementing a solution which uses the Google Translate API (advanced edition). We have an issue now, because we found that translating identical input results in different outputs.

For example, the dutch input string "Goudse 48+ kaas belegen 1/16 Noord Hollandse weidemelk" is translated to French.

The first output gives: "Gouda 48+ fromage affiné 1/16 **Lait de prairie** de Hollande du Nord"

The second output gives: "Gouda 48+ fromage affiné 1/16 **Lait des prés** de Hollande du Nord"

This while being translated shortly after each other. In total, within one file of ± 250 products and ± 25 colums, 267 differences appear.

Does anyone know how this is possible? Or what we can do about it?

Comment: Hi JJ. I'm also experiencing this behavior, did you find a solution?